# How do you convert shapely multipolygon to polygon

Tags: python, polygon, shapely

I have shapely multipolygon, how can I convert that to list of polygons?

```
polygons = [Polygon(cham_geom), Polygon(neighbor_geom)]
boundary = cascaded_union(polygons)  # results in multipolygon sometimes
if boundary.geom_type == 'MultiPolygon':
       # extract polygons out of multipolygon
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MultiPolygon is iterable via `geoms` attribute, so you can do for loop over polygons within multipolygon.

```
polygons = [Polygon(cham_geom), Polygon(neighbor_geom)]
boundary = cascaded_union(polygons)  # results in multipolygon sometimes
if boundary.geom_type == 'MultiPolygon':
   # extract polygons out of multipolygon
   list = []
   for polygon in boundary.geoms:
       list.append(polygon)
```